# Adding share extension to the existing project. So the already existing project pod starts getting errors

Tags: swift, swift5, swift4.2, share-extension

When we add a share extension to the existing project. So the already existing project pods start getting errors because your code is in `Swift 4`  and the extension is in `Swift 5`.

When I add a pod in the extension target, an error occurs on the pod install both targets have different swift version. then we change the share extension `swift 5 to 4.2`. Then the pod is installed. But when I run the project, errors appear in the pods already included in the project.

1. `KVNProgress`
2. `IQKeyboardManagerSwift`
3. `CameraManager`
4. `Gallery`

If anyone has an idea how we can solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Set to Allow API Extension to No to particular framework who gives this e
error like IQKeyboardManager

Consider you facing this issue for IQKeyboardManager and you installed this framework using Pod. Then your project click on Pod -> CLick on IqkeyboardManager.

And set Allow API Extension to No